# How to use the same output binding on different tab panels in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In my `server.R` file, I have a reactive called `myNet` which generates a [`visNetwork`](http://dataknowledge.github.io/visNetwork/). In my `ui.R`, I have multiple tab panels that *ideally* will have different input widgets that effect the `visNetwork`.

Is it possible to re-use the same binding?

Currently, when I try to run the code similar to below, I receive an error: `Uncaught Duplicate binding for ID vis`.

---

#### Snippet of `server.R`

```
  myNet <- reactive({
    nodes <- df_nodes
    edges <- df_edges        
    visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = '800px')
  })

  output$vis <- renderVisNetwork(
    myNet()
  )
```

---

#### Snippet of `ui.R`

```
  ...

  tabPanel("First Panel",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("input1", "Title 1", 
                    min=1, max=10, value=1),
        sliderInput("input2", "Title 2",
                    min=1, max=10, value=1),
        sliderInput("input3", "Title 3",
                    min=1, max=10, value=1)
      ),
      mainPanel(
        visNetworkOutput("vis", height = '800px') # *** ISSUE HERE***
      )
    )
  ),
  tabPanel("Second Panel",
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("input4", "Title 4", 
                    min=1, max=10, value=1),
        sliderInput("input5", "Title 5",
                    min=1, max=10, value=1),
      ),
      mainPanel(
        visNetworkOutput("vis", height = '800px') # *** ISSUE HERE***       
      )
    )
  ), ...
```

Comment: Nope, sorry. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde What do you think would be the best way to implement this type of behavior? That is, the output/plot is affected by different controls that are on different "panels" -- are conditional panels my only outlet?

Comment: Abstract the code in `renderVisNetwork` (or whatever your render function is called) into a `reactive` expression, then call that reactive expression in your two render functions.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Hmm...just feels really un-DRY. Everything is already abstracted into `myNet()` -- so basically I have to create `output$vis_1 <- renderVisNetwork(myNet())` and `output$vis_2 <- renderVisNetwork(myNet())` and so on...

Comment: Exactly. That's as dry as you're going to get. It sounds like there might be a better place for your output than within your tabs, ie, some other place in your interface

Comment: Thanks +1 - maybe I'll play with `conditionalPanel` to accomplish the same thing without re-rendering. May also move this [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get more input.

Comment: I would also suggest opening a github issue or contacting Joe Cheng, since I've seen a lot of people asking this exact question in the past few weeks, so maybe it is time for shiny to start thinking about a potential solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up opening [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/867). The consensus appears to be that the following is the best method:

`output$vis_1 <- output$vis_2 <- renderVisNetwork(myNet())`

Alternatively, as alluded to in the comments, you could use a not-so-DRY approach:

```
output$vis_1 <- renderVisNetwork(myNet())
output$vis_2 <- renderVisNetwork(myNet())
```

Joe Cheng appropriately made the following comment on the GitHub issue:

> *"Allowing multiple outputs to share the same ID would have a lot of gnarly side effects, it makes my head hurt to even think about what it would mean. For example, two Leaflet maps with the same ID--but they both have lots of state in the browser, and communicate that state back to the client. How can you make sense of that when they share the same ID?*"

All said and told, I was able to ahieve the same behavior using the [dynamic UI](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-ui.html) approach with a switch that toggles which controls are displayed to the user via `uiOutput()` (in the `ui.R` file) and `output$ui <- renderUI({...})` (in the `server.R` file).